# Cypress recording

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, video-recording, cypress-configuration

just wanted to ask if this is possible to change the location folder for recorded file? I am running tests for two different applications, one after another, and when tests are finished for both of them, I can only access the latest recording.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `videosFolder` attribute in your [cypress config file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files) with the folder path.

```js
videosFolder: 'cypress/videos_project_2'
```

You can override the videosFolder path from the CLI, something like this:

```js
npx cypress run --config videosFolder=cypress/videos_project_2
```

In your `package.json`, create two scripts like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test:project1": "npx cypress run --config videosFolder=cypress/videos_project_1",
  "test:project2": "npx cypress run --config videosFolder=cypress/videos_project_2",
}
```

Then as per the project, directly run the commands:

```js
npm run test:project1
//or
npm run test:project2
```

Comment: And is it possible to have to different folders for different scripts? Eg. one command will have cypress run <folder_1> and the second cypress run <folder 2>

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set `trashAssetsBeforeRuns`.

See [Videos](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos#Videos)

> Cypress clears any existing videos before a cypress run. If you do not want to clear your videos folder before a run, you can set trashAssetsBeforeRuns to false.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    video: true,
    trashAssetsBeforeRuns: false
  },
});
```